# XAMPP not working when I go to localhost - just get It Works

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I am trying to use XAMPP on my Mac OS. I have installed XAMPP, it is in my Applications folder, and I have started running it. When I go to localhost, I just get "It Works!". I remember messing with localhost years ago, but forget what I did. Does anyone know what I did to get It Works! there? And how can I un-configure what I have done and get XAMPP working for localhost?

Thanks

Comment: check the port from xampp control panel >config > Apache httpd.conf, and then visit                  localhost:port/

Comment: thanks! this helped

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could check:

- Make sure everything is running correctly for XAMPP. Go to XAMPP Control (by going to `/Applications/XAMPP/manager-osx.app` in Finder) and make sure to start Apache and MySQL on the Manage Servers tab
- Check what you have in `htdocs` in `\Applications\XAMPP\xamppfiles\htdocs\`
- If your servers are still not starting, make sure to try the following if on OS X:

  - The apache server that comes pre-installed in OS X might be running. Try `sudo apachectl stop`. If that doesnt work, then try `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

For more info make sure to check this website. 
[Install and test XAMPP for Mac](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-install-start-test-xampp-on-mac-osx.cfm)

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP. Any idea why none of my servers will run?

Comment: @bodubs What are you getting? Make sure you have the correct class file permissions on the `htdocs` folder

Comment: Class file permissions are all set. None of the servers will start when I go to XAMPP Control and then to Manager Servers tab and click start for each of them. I tried the unix command in that original link you sent for MySQL Database, but it still would not start.

Comment: My guess is the apache server that comes pre-installed in OS X is running. Try `sudo apachectl stop`. If that doesnt work, then try `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` @bodubs

Comment: @bodubs awesome! I've updated my answer to include the last steps.